# Jmeter deveation is more but the report has zero errors

Tags: jmeter

rampup - 400
Thread- 100
Loop count -10

Deveation is more than average value ...as per my knowledge deveation should be less or half of the average and report has 0 errors

Can anyone tell me what happens if deveation is more and developers going to fix this

And I'm I giving the ramp up time correct what should be rampup period in general for 100 users ...when I give for same input rampup has 100 I'm getting time out errors in my report

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Standard Deviation** is a measure of the variability of a data set. This is a standard statistical measure. See, for example: [Standard Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) entry at Wikipedia. JMeter calculates the population standard deviation (e.g. STDEVP function in spreadsheets), not the sample standard deviation (e.g. STDEV).

As per [Understanding Your Reports: Part 3 - Key Statistics Performance Testers Need to Understand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-3-key-statistics-performance-testers-need-understand)

> **Standard Deviations**
>
> The standard deviation is the measurement of the density of the cluster of the data around the sought value (mean). Low standard deviation means that points are closer to the mean. High standard deviation means the points are farther away. This parameter can help determine how reliable the data is. If the standard deviation is high, this means that results vary very much, and the analysis should be conducted accordingly.

If you have standard deviation higher than the average response time it basically means that you have more samplers with response time above the average than the ones which response time is below the average. Not sure if there is anything to fix there, maybe it's expected that some samplers last longer than otherse, for example "Logout" operation is normally very quick and "search" operations can last longer, if your user does multiple searches and only one logout - the deviation will be higher than the average. You can look at i.e. 90%, 95% and 99% lines of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener to see which percentage of users have for each and every action (and overall), compare the values with your NFRs or SLAs and raise issues if necessary.

Per se deviation higher than the average doesn't necessarily mean that there is a performance problem, you need to correlate other metrics with the business requirements

Comment: thanks can u please tell me how can we take ramp up time ...can consider looking at the html report num of hits per sec min value is 12  so can I consider ramp up as 10 for 100 users is that a good value to give ...